# How to enter seconds in a Userform Timer?

Tags: excel, vba, timer

I have a program that uses a VBA countdown timer.

I can only enter minutes. How can I enter seconds?

In Module1 I enter the time

```
Public Const AllowedTime As Double = 1
```

and the code looks like this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim T, E, M As Double, S As Double

T = Timer
Do
    E = CDbl(Time) * 24 * 60 * 60 - T
    M = AllowedTime - 1 - Int(E / 60)
    S = 59 - Round((E / 60 - Int(E / 60)) * 60, 0)

    With tBx1
        .Value = Format(CStr(M), "00") & ":" & Format(CStr(S), "00")
    End With
    DoEvents
Loop Until (Timer - T) / 60 >= AllowedTime
End Sub

Private Sub poker_Initialize()
Dim M As Double, S As Double
M = Int(AllowedTime)
S = (AllowedTime - Int(AllowedTime)) * 60
With tBx1
    .Value = Format(CStr(M), "00") & ":" & Format(CStr(S), "00")
End With
End Sub
```

Here is a simple working example
https://app.box.com/s/211uo88dk02x6il8hqj19wyiv1rli2sj

Comment: What do you mean by "enter minutes"?

Comment: Oh, sorry, the value I put into allowed time I called minutes.  If I put .5 it gives me 1 minute not 30 seconds.  What I would like is to enter .5 for 30 seconds or at least 30 for 30 seconds.  Thanks

Comment: I suggest you edit your original question to include that explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you use `Date` variables for your time calculations because it is much easier.

You will also need a module-level variable if you want the Pause button to work. This code lets you show minutes & seconds. Your `AllowedTime` variable should be minutes with a decimal part for seconds, or change it to the number of seconds and change the lines that are commented out.

```
Dim userClickedPause As Boolean ' Gets set to True by the Pause button

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim stopTime As Date

    userClickedPause = False
    ' If AllowedTime is the number of minutes with a decimal part:
    stopTime = DateAdd("s", Int(AllowedTime * 60), Now) ' add seconds to current time

    ' If AllowedTime is the number of seconds:
    'stopTime = DateAdd("s", AllowedTime, Now) ' add seconds to current time
    Do
        With tBx1
            .Value = Format(stopTime - Now, "Nn:Ss")
        End With
        DoEvents
        If userClickedPause = True Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop Until Now >= stopTime

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    userClickedPause = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  You managed to solve 2 issues, I needed the seconds for a work around for the pause button.  Thanks Again

Comment: The timer works great, But my other timer would activate other codes.  Also it would loop until i stopped it, when your code loops in starts counting up.  I should have put this code to start with but I did not think of it, the other was already in box.  I would appricate any help.     https://app.box.com/s/junlof2b5yc8catml214hmv783vup41q

Comment: I suggest you improve the names of your variables (single letters are not meaningful to other people) and add some comments and then post a new question.